# Subspaces of $\Bbb R^3$

Tags: vector-spaces

Given
$U=\{(1, -1, 3)^t\}$ and $V_a=\{(x, 3x-az,z)^t\}$ for any $a\in\mathbb{R}$, how to determine $a$, such that $U \cap V_a = \{o\} \land U+V_a=\mathbb{R}^3$?

I already found out that $V_a$ always describes a plane in this 3D space, because its base is $\{(1,3,0)^t,(0,-a,1)^t\}$ ($\dim(V)=2$) and that in order to satisfy both conditions, the line determined by $U$ should not lie within this plane and the line should cross the plane in $o$.

However, I forgot much of the algebra of my senior year and don't remember how exactly I am supposed to find out if a line is contained in the plane or not. I tried to set a vector equation:
$$(1,-1,3)^t = l_1 (1,3,0)^t + l_2 (0,-a,1)^t + l_3 (0, 0, 0)$$
but that yields a solution for the $l$'s and not for my $a$.

Comment: What does $\{o\} \land U$ mean?

Comment: These are simply two conditions: U∩Va={o} AND U+Va=R3.

Comment: And by $o$ did you mean zero?

Comment: yes, o is (0,0,0)^t

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have $V_a = \operatorname{sp} \{(1,3,0)^T, (0,-a,1)^T \}$.
Then $(1,-1,3)^T \in V_a$ **iff** $a = \frac{4}{3}$.

Since $\dim V_a = 2$, then $\dim (V_a + \operatorname{sp} ( U)) = 2 $ **iff** $(1,-1,3)^T \in V_a$.

Comment: Thanks. Silly that I dodn't think of it in this way. Btw: What does sp() mean?

Comment: It means the linear hull or span. We have $\operatorname{sp} V = \{ \sum_k \alpha_k v_k | v_k \in V \}$ (The $\alpha_k$ are scalars in the relevant field and the sum is finite).